# Ethernet (intermittent) +wifi (not working) in 14.04 on HP Elitebook 725

Tags: 14.04, wireless, hp, ethernet

I have purchased an HP Elitebook 725 and installed Ubuntu to dual boot with Windows. Initially I installed 14.10 but, following discussion at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2254816, I have installed instead 14.04. On both 14.04 and 14.10 the wifi is not working and the ethernet is intermittent (by which I mean I can ping some sites and not others and can occasionally connect to a website with firefox but only by repeated use of Crlt-R).

Below I past the output of the wireless script from http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=370108

I am way out of my depth but nevertheless would like to have the wifi working (and ethernet if possible). After three days of trying to solve this problem I seem to be no further forward, and would appreciate any help or advice. With grateful thanks, Martin.

---

```
======== Wireless-Info START ========
```

System-Info ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
martin 3.13.0-32-generic x86_64,  Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS, trusty

CPU    : AMD A10 PRO-7350B R6, 10 Compute Cores 4C+6G
Memory : 6858 MB
Uptime : 21:53:38 up 12 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.29, 0.14, 0.12
```

lspci ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0e)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:221d]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4359]
    Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:05e2]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
```

lsusb ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b466 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0a5c:21f1 Broadcom Corp. HP Portable Bumble Bee
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 138a:003f Validity Sensors, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 0718:0a02 Imation Corp. 
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

PCMCIA Card Info ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

iwconfig ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
```

rfkill ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
      Interface            Soft blocked  Hard blocked
0: hci0: Bluetooth             no            no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN          no            no
2: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN      no            no
```

lsmod ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
wl                   4207846  0 
hp_wmi                 14062  0 
lib80211               14381  2 wl,lib80211_crypt_tkip
sparse_keymap          13948  1 hp_wmi
cfg80211              484040  1 wl
wmi                    19177  1 hp_wmi
```

module parameters ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
cfg80211      (2): cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz=N | ieee80211_regdom=00
wmi           (2): debug_dump_wdg=N | debug_event=N
```

nm-tool ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
State: connecting
============================o=============o========o=======================================o=========o===========o==============o===========
 Interface & ID             | Type        | Driver | State                                 | Default | Speed     | Support      | HW Addr   
============================o=============o========o=======================================o=========o===========o==============o===========
 wlan0                      | 802.11 WiFi | wl     | disconnected                          | no      |           | WEP/WPA/WPA2 | <MAC wlan0>
----------------------------+-------------+--------+---------------------------------------+---------+-----------+--------------+-----------
 eth0  [Wired connection 1] | Wired       | r8169  | connecting (getting IP configuration) | no      | 100 Mb/s  |              | <MAC eth0>
----------------------------+-------------+--------+---------------------------------------+---------+-----------+--------------+-----------
```

NetworkManager.state ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true
```

NetworkManager.conf ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

NM WiFi Profiles ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

interfaces ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

resolv.conf ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Routes & Ping ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
```

iw reg get ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
(Region : "en_GB.UTF-8")
country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
```

iwlist chan ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
wlan0     32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 (2.412 GHz) - 14 (2.484 GHz)
          Channel 32 (5.16 GHz)
          Channel 34 (5.17 GHz)
          Channel 36 (5.18 GHz)
          Channel 38 (5.19 GHz)
          Channel 40 (5.2 GHz)
          Channel 42 (5.21 GHz)
          Channel 44 (5.22 GHz)
          Channel 46 (5.23 GHz)
          Channel 48 (5.24 GHz)
          Channel 50 (5.25 GHz)
          Channel 52 (5.26 GHz)
          Channel 54 (5.27 GHz)
          Channel 56 (5.28 GHz)
          Channel 58 (5.29 GHz)
          Channel 60 (5.3 GHz)
          Channel 62 (5.31 GHz)
          Channel 64 (5.32 GHz)
          Channel 66 (5.33 GHz) - 14 (2.484 GHz)
```

iwlist scan ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
No way to aquire root rights found.
```

blacklist ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma
```

modinfo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
[wl]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/updates/dkms/wl.ko
srcversion:     FF25FE784DC6BDFF69DAFCB
depends:        cfg80211,lib80211
parm:           wl_txq_thresh:int
parm:           oneonly:int
parm:           piomode:int
parm:           instance_base:int
parm:           nompc:int
parm:           intf_name:string

[hp_wmi]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/platform/x86/hp-wmi.ko
srcversion:     22DCD1B7DA09178B45B1068
depends:        wmi,sparse-keymap

[lib80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/kernel/net/wireless/lib80211.ko
srcversion:     84DEF767F03D28E373F18E5
depends:        

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
srcversion:     E786D076B61F97809B04B64
depends:        
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

[wmi]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/platform/x86/wmi.ko
srcversion:     CED5410F008DC70DF5F064B
depends:        
parm:           debug_event:Log WMI Events [0/1] (bool)
parm:           debug_dump_wdg:Dump available WMI interfaces [0/1] (bool)
```

udev rules ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC eth0>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

# PCI device 0x14e4:0x4359 (wl)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC wlan0>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"
```

Custom files/entries ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
/etc/modules        : Default
/etc/rc.local       : Default
/etc/modprobe.d     : Not Default
/etc/pm/(cnf|pw|sl) : Default

[/etc/modprobe.d]
iwlwifi.conf      : remove iwlwifi \
                    (/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
                    && /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
mlx4.conf         : softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en
```

Kernel boot line ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic root=UUID=7d8c4358-d805-4853-9a29-56afd4ad7db8 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
```

dmesg ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
[    1.238091] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.00 <tigran@aivazian.fsnet.co.uk>, Peter Oruba
[    1.238564] audit: initializing netlink socket (disabled)
[    2.046747] r8169 Gigabit Ethernet driver 2.3LK-NAPI loaded
[    2.046917] r8169 0000:01:00.0 (unregistered net_device): unknown MAC, using family default
[    7.805713] wmi: Mapper loaded
[    8.194970] usb 3-3: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
[    8.195879] Bluetooth: can't load firmware, may not work correctly
[    8.358388] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.
[    8.361932] wl: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
[    8.432394] INFO @wl_cfg80211_attach : Registered CFG80211 phy
[    8.494806] wlan0: Broadcom BCM4359 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 6.30.223.141 (r415941)
[   10.206855] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[  760.016590] ERROR @wl_dev_intvar_get : error (-1)
[  760.016598] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_tx_power : error (-1)

======== Done ========
```

---

Answer (score 0):

after hours of scrounging around myself, I have found a fairly comprehensive solution table to all the broadcom drivers on this other question at S.O. / ask ubuntu

[Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers/60395#60395)